# Is there a R function to find make column values based on one column variable?

Tags: r, tidyr, dplyr

I am trying to get spatial coordinates of related objects into new columns based on relationship identities in another column. However, I haven't managed to figure out the right way to do so. 
Here's what my data frame looks like

```
    object   parent x-pos y-pos
 1:     Z        A 0.5 0.7
 2:     B        A 0.1 0.0
 3:     C        E 4.6 2.5
 4:     D        E 5.6 5.0
 5:     A        B 0.2 1.0
 6:     P        B 0.4 2.0
```

What I want to add to this data frame is two new columns of x-pos-parent and y-pos-parent based on the parent information in the "parent column", for every unique object in the "object" column? Any help would be greatly appreciated...

The expected df should look

```
like so
```

```
     object   parent x-pos y-pos x-pos-parent y-pos-parent
 1:     Z        A   0.5   0.7   0.2          1.0
 2:     B        A   0.1   0.0   0.2          1.0
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the expected output would look like. Can you write by hand what you expect to get?

Comment: My best guess - row 1 has parent `A`, so we look at the row with `object = A` (row 5) and pull the `x_pos` and `y_pos` values into row 1's new columns, `x_pos_parent` and `y_pos_parent`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this only goes one deep, you could do a `left_join` or equivalent:

```
library(dplyr)

DF%>%
  left_join(., ., by = c('parent' = 'object'))%>%
  select(-parent.y)

  object parent x.pos.x y.pos.x x.pos.y y.pos.y
1      Z      A     0.5     0.7     0.2       1
2      B      A     0.1     0.0     0.2       1
3      C      E     4.6     2.5      NA      NA
4      D      E     5.6     5.0      NA      NA
5      A      B     0.2     1.0     0.1       0
6      P      B     0.4     2.0     0.1       0
```

You can also do a `data.table` update join:

```
DT <- as.data.table(DF)
DT[DT
   , on = .(parent = object)
   , `:=`(x_pos_par = i.x.pos
          , y_pos_par = i.y.pos)]

DT
   object parent x.pos y.pos x_pos_par y_pos_par
1:      Z      A   0.5   0.7       0.2         1
2:      B      A   0.1   0.0       0.2         1
3:      C      E   4.6   2.5        NA        NA
4:      D      E   5.6   5.0        NA        NA
5:      A      B   0.2   1.0       0.1         0
6:      P      B   0.4   2.0       0.1         0
```

If you have more than one level of recursion, you should look into the package `igraph`.

**Data**

```
Lines <- "object   parent x-pos y-pos
1     Z        A 0.5 0.7
2     B        A 0.1 0.0
3     C        E 4.6 2.5
4     D        E 5.6 5.0
5     A        B 0.2 1.0
6     P        B 0.4 2.0"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```